# convert from string javascript to access datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime, ms-access, adodb, activexobject

I am working with ADODB to connect my javascript with ms.access (hell yeah I know it shouldn't use js) and using in IE8.
I can connect, insert, update, delete well. But the problem when I want to insert or update specific row with datatype datetime in access, can you help me how to convert datatype string so it can compatible in datetime ms.access.

I have tried to convert it into Date, but the error still show type mismatch... and here is my code

```js
var adoConn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var adoRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

adoConn.Open(conString);
adoRS.Open("SELECT * FROM tableName", adoConn, 1, 3);

var s = new Date("11/27/2014");
adoRS.AddNew;
adoRS.Fields("myDateColumn").value = s;
adoRS.Update;
adoRS.Close();
adoRS = null;
adoConn.Close();
adoConn = null;
```

I already have searched through some website that explains connection to access, eventhough they don't give some examples about datetime problem, thanks before

Comment: try using international date format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: thanks for the idea, but it's still have no effect. I change the String into full format, and the error still show

Comment: whats the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').slice(0, -5)
```

Comment: Try to include an explanation on what your code does so OP actually understands it.

Answer (score 1):

The JScript `Date` object offers the [`getVarDate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d4x3w61%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method for the purpose of converting the `Date` to VT_DATE format (which is expected by ADODB):

```
adoRS.Fields("myDateColumn").value = s.getVarDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh finally I know my bad. I should try not to convert into date first,
I try to insert with datatype string directly and it really shock me, because success!
Furthermore if you want to insert date with value "1/2/2014", try to change it into 2 digit in month and date value. So it must be "01/02/2014"

Comment: Are you aware that **(1)** the Access Database Engine (ACE) will always interpret '01/02/2014' as January 2, even on machines where the Short Date format has been set to `dd/mm/yyyy` in Windows, and **(2)** ACE will accept the unambiguous `yyyy/mm/dd` format and interpret it correctly?

Comment: yes I know (1), I always work with pattern mm/dd/yyyy
(2) I just know about that, thanks anyway